# Unity Game Analytics

Tags: unity-game-engine, analytics

I was researching about what type of analytic tool I should use, and I found

go.gameanalytics.com

I wanted to make a custom design event fired, so I tried

```
    GA.API.Design.NewEvent("Test:One", 1F);
```

From Window->GameAnalytics->Open GA_Status Window

I could see that design events have been fired around 1300 times (I intended to)

But when I went to explore window, and try to see my design events, I saw none.

In fact, from Explore window, and Look up metric, I saw only "Core" and no design.

You may think that I have typed some keys wrong, but when I tried

```
    GA.API.Debug.NewEvent(-------)
```

I saw debug messages appearing in home window from real-time tap.

I know from other screenshots that I suppose to see "Core", "Design", and "Business" metrics. Only having "Core" is definitely abnormal.

Someone can say that I didn't wait 24 hours, 
but I tried this since yesterday, so I have waited 24 hours.

How can I browse my design events?